# R: Importing All Files From a Directory with a Certain Name

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have a main folder - this main folder contains several subfolders and each subfolder contains several sub-subfolders. Within each sub-subfolder, I have Excel files with names like : aaa_b.xlsx, aaa_new.xlsx, aaa_old.xlsx, etc.

**My Question**:

- Suppose the name of the main folder is "folder1" (it's saved in the working directory, i.g. getwd())
  Within each of these sub-subfolders, I want to import all files that have the word "aaa" and do not include the word "old"
- I want each file to be keep the same name in R
- The final result should be individual data frames within the global environment

Here is what I tried so far:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

main_folder <- "folder1"

subfolders <- list.dirs(main_folder, recursive = TRUE)

files <- subfolders %>%
  map(~dir(., pattern = "aaa.*xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)) %>%
  unlist()

old_files <- grep("old", basename(files))

files <- files[-old_files]
```

Everything up to here works - I can view all the names of the files.

My Problem: From here, I can not import the files

```
    data_list <- setNames(lapply(files, read_excel), tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files)))

Error: Evaluation Error: zip file '....' cannot be opened
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

I suspect that the problem is that the path names are somehow not being read correctly. For example, I am able to successfully import single file if I manually specify the whole path:

```
name = getwd()
a = read_excel(paste0(name, "/folder1", "/subfolder1", "/subsubfolder1/", "aaa_new.xlsx"))
```

Is there some "low-risk" fool-proof way that imports all the files without getting lost in the path names?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems at least one of your file is not a valid excel file. You could simply do `files <- list.files(main_folder, pattern = "xlsx$", recursive = T, full.names = T)`. Then `files <- files[!grepl("old", files)]`.

Comment: @jeanlain: thank you for your reply! When I try this, I get the error: main_folder not found ....this error does not come when i use list.dirs() instead. any ideas?

Comment: It should work. `list.files` and `list.dirs`work the same with respect to the directory that is scanned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way. Untested.

```
files <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
i <- grepl("aaa", basename(files)) 
j <- grepl("old", basename(files))
files <- files[i & !j]

data_list <- tryCatch(
  lapply(files, read_excel),
  error = function(e) e
)
ok <- !sapply(data_list, inherits, "error")
wrong_list <- data_list[!ok]
data_list <- data_list[ok]
data_list <- setNames(data_list, files[ok])
```

I don't like your use of `file_path_sans_ext/basename`, imagine that there are files with the same name in different sub-subfolders, then the same name will be assigned to different `data_list` members. That is why I have assigned the fully qualified filenames to the list's names.

Comment: @ Rui: thank you for your reply! do i need to replace path = "." with the actual name?

Comment: @stats_noob If it's the wd you want, no.